# Webservice SOAP request - Wrong type of data sent

Tags: php, web-services, soap

**Context / What I want :**

I'm facing an issue while calling a Webservice with SOAP. Here's an image the relevant part of the WS I want to call : 
[image: Picture of the WS I want to call]

(I voluntarily hide the namespace part, not relevant here)

I want to send data through **'Demande_de_mot_de_passe'** function and catch result from this request.

In the code below, this request is correct (the name of the function is good), I guess the problem is the formatting of the data I want to send. The call of the function is made with this part :

```
$client->Demande_de_mot_de_passe($soapVar);
```

**What I've tried :**

Here's the relevant part of the code I've tried ( I voluntarily change values of data but nothing else. There is no typo error with the brackets, it close the function and the class I didn't put here to keep the relevant part) :

```
    $client = new \SoapClient('URL_OF_THE_WS?WSDL', array(
      'trace'        => 1,
      'encoding'     => 'UTF-8',
      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
      'classmap'     => array('Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input' => 'Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input')
    ));

    $donnesUtilisateur = new Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input;
    $donnesUtilisateur->Code_societe = '000';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Ident_type   = 'A';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Ident_code   = 'xxxxxx';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Dat_demande  = '00000000';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Adr_mail     = 'xxxxxx';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Adr_cpos     = 'xxxxxx';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Nom          = 'xxxxxx';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Prenom       = 'xxxxxx';
    $donnesUtilisateur->Dat_naiss    = '00000000';
    $namespace = 'URL_OF_NAMESPACE';

    $soapVar = new \SoapVar($donnesUtilisateur, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input', $namespace);

    $result = $client->Demande_de_mot_de_passe($soapVar);

    print_r($result);

  }
}

class Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input {
  public $Code_societe;
  public $Ident_type;
  public $Ident_code;
  public $Dat_demande;
  public $Adr_cpos;
  public $Adr_mail;
  public $Nom;
  public $Prenom;
  public $Dat_naiss;
}
```

I've also tried with passing array of casting an object with the array like this (without success)  :

```
$donnesUtilisateur =  [
      'Code_societe' => '000',
      'Ident_type'  => 'A',
      'Ident_code'  => 'xxxxxx',
      'Dat_demande' => '00000000',
      'Adr_cpos'    => 'xxxxxx',
      'Adr_mail'    => 'xxxxxx',
      'Nom'         => 'xxxxxx',
      'Prenom'      => 'xxxxxx',
      'Dat_naiss'   => '00000000',
    ];
```

and :

```
$donnesUtilisateur = (object) [
      'Code_societe' => '000',
      'Ident_type'  => 'A',
      'Ident_code'  => 'xxxxxx',
      'Dat_demande' => '00000000',
      'Adr_cpos'    => 'xxxxxx',
      'Adr_mail'    => 'xxxxxx',
      'Nom'         => 'xxxxxx',
      'Prenom'      => 'xxxxxx',
      'Dat_naiss'   => '00000000',
    ];
```

**Error I get :**

```
SoapFault: Did not receive a 'Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input' object. in SoapClient->__call()
```

If I unterstand clearly, the formatting of data sent is not correct but when I try other way to send it, it still reporting the same error.

**Docs I've read about without success :**

http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Php:_Soap:_How_to_add_attribute_to_SoapVar

http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-soap/066jkmcz2h/passing-objects-to-soap-server-complextype-classmap

**EDIT**

Here's a capture of the WS 'Demande_de_mot_de_passe' function call in SoapUI : 
[image: Capture of WS in SoapUI]

(Sorry for the long post, I hope it is clear enough, don't forget to ask about precisions if needed, thanks in advance for your help :) )

Comment: AFAIK, your problem is with SoapVar implementation and complexity of complexType. As I can see, your request message need a parameter called `Demande_de_mot_de_passe` and inside of it need a parameter called `Demande_de_mot_de_passe_input`. Your example doesn't show how is the method name (just your code), and I think it's wrong. Try open the WSDL with SoapUI and see what it'll show as request message. At last, your SoapVar implementation has a few mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the method name is good (if I try a wrong one, an other error is triggered), an other developer did a call to this Webservice with a Python script and it works fine. But he just pass data through an associative array and I can't figure out why this doesn't work with my PHP adapted script. Thanks for your time mate :)

Comment: Did you open the WSDL with SoapUI? Show me the request message or the entire WSDL.

Comment: In the SoapUI, I've been able to send a "Demande_de_mot_de_passe" request with those parameters I've explained in my PHP code. (those in $donnesUtilisateur) 
However, I don't know what's wrong in my PHP code. Thanks for your time

Comment: that's what I need to help you, see what SoapUI is creating as XML request.

Comment: I've edited my post with a capture of what I get in SoapUI. I also have an issue with fields that start with '0' value, like in 'Code_Societe' attribute.

Comment: I can see some problems with your request creation, but I need one more information, the style of SOAP binding. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/
But I'll write an answer for both case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your WSDL's type, there's a sequence named `Demande_de_mot_de_passe` which use a element named `Demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest` and not `Demande_de_mot_de_passe_Input`.

Your print from SoapUI describe the message request, but if it's `document` style, `Demande_de_mot_de_passe` is a type. On the other hand if it's `RPC` is the method name.

Starting if it's RPC you can do as showed below. You should use as native object as you can (SOAP will work better with they). A stdObject will be good enough:

```
$request = new stdClass();

$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Code_societe = '000';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Ident_type = 'A';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Ident_code = 'xxxxxx';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Dat_demande = '00000000';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Adr_mail = 'xxxxxx';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Adr_cpos = 'xxxxxx';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Nom = 'xxxxxx';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Prenom = 'xxxxxx';
$demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest->Dat_naiss = '00000000';

$request->Demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest = $demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest;

$response = $client->Demande_de_mot_de_passe($request);
```

If your SOAP binding is document, you just have to add a new upper level named `Demande_de_mot_de_passe`

```
/** The variable $demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest is created as above **/

$demande_de_mot_de_passe = new stdClass();
$demande_de_mot_de_passe->Demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest = $demande_de_mot_de_passeRequest;
$request->Demande_de_mot_de_passe = $demande_de_mot_de_passe;

$response = $client->Demande_de_mot_de_passe($request);
```

Your WSDL doesn't need a list/collections (it's not your case), so you don't need to create/parse variables with SoapVar. There's others examples that you can read about (one is mine, but it's in portuguese) and other is about the BOGUS node:

http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/535213-enviar-xml-via-soap/?p=2137411
http://www.fischco.org/blog/2011/3/26/php-soapserver-objects-arrays-and-encoding.html

Comment: I've also an issue with integer fields that start with '0', in truncate the number. Example : 005 becomes 5. Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: For integer zero left have no meaning. Change the format to string. It's have to be done for serial number, phone, postal code and each other any format which could start with zero.

Comment: Hello, I can't change the format to string because the Webservice doesn't depend on me. Do you know a way I can get around of this in my php code ?

Comment: If the number will always have the same length or based on some rule, use [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to prepend the zeros. If it's variable, well, there's no way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, it don't work. I use `str_pad(5,3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)` to get `005` but the WS still interpret it as `5` :/

Comment: Are you sending the number or receiving? If you are sending a string formated "005" (with leading zeros), and web service are receinveng just "5", sorry but there's no way to work around it, number is a number and zero left has no meaning. The problem isn't your, it's from WS.

Comment: I'm sending the number, I afraid I've been through the same opinion as yours, that the problem is from the WS. But the same call to this WS works with a Python script based on suds webservice : https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation 
So I was thinking, there could be a workaround in PHP too. 
Thanks for your time mate

Comment: If you want take a look at generated xml using the method [SoapClient::__getLastRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) with trace option enabled. If the number is "5" and not "005" at XML, maybe you can do something. But it's is just a guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131054/discussion-between-vincent-g-and-gabriel-heming).