# How to deal with abstract types in WSDL-enabled SoapClient?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I need to handle external SOAP service with WSDL. Example of valid request (simplified) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <RunCommand xmlns="https://me.com/MyService">
            <request>
                <Credentials>
                    <User>jack</User>
                    <Password>abc123</Password>
                </Credentials>
                <Command xsi:type="SomeCommand">
                    <Foo>bar</Foo>
                </Command>
            </request>
        </RunCommand>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is that according to WSDL, `Command` element is of abstract `CommandType` type, so I need to specify `xsi:type`. I know how to do it with `SoapVar`, but it seems like if I use `SoapVar`, all WSDL-mode automation is gone.

For simple WSDLs, that would be enough:

```
$soapClient->RunCommand([
    'Request' => [
        'Credentials' => [
            'user' => 'jack',
            'password' => 'abc123',
        ],
        'Command' => [
            'Foo' => 'bar'
        ]
    ]   
]);
```

But in this case, I'm getting an exception:

> The specified type is abstract: name='CommandType'

I know how to make `Command` element for `SoapClient`, but I'm not sure how to mix it all together. I tried this:

```
$soapClient->RunCommand([
    'Request' => [
        'Credentials' => [
            'user' => 'jack',
            'password' => 'abc123',
        ],
        new SoapVar(
            ['Foo' => 'bar'],
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            'CommandType',
            null,
            'Command'
        )
    ]   
]);
```

But it doesn't create a request I need. How can I form the request I need with SoapClient to keep as much WSDL goodies as possible?

Comment: Have you tried to call using SoapUI? Try out the link above and the examples links (there are a few examples with SoapVar): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994425/webservice-soap-request-wrong-type-of-data-sent/41101969#41101969

Comment: SoapUI is no help here, because I know how the request should be built like. There are no SoapVar examples that would help in that topic neither. :(

Comment: How not, he creates the request for you, just have to fill with values. If SoapUI doesn't create the request, there's something wrong with your WSDL. The two links at the end =).

Comment: In my question you can see that I know the XML request, I even gave you an example. That's not what my question is about. The question is how to form this request with SoapClient.