# PHP SoapClient - Creating a request with a variable

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am attempting to create a SOAP request in PHP. I am very new to this and struggling quite a bit. The web service I am using takes a vehicle's VIN as an input and sends back details regarding that specific vehicle. Enter: `1ZVHT88S375260112` and in return you will receive details about the 2007 Ford Mustang to which that VIN belongs to.

I have created a simple input bar and form to enter the VIN. This will feed into a page with the PHP SOAP Request. I have also created a SOAP envelope with my WSDL link. I have omitted my login credentials (username & password/secret).

How can I take the VIN input and my envelope and create a SOAP request using SoapClient in PHP? Any inputs or help would be appreciated!

Simple HTML Input/Form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input {width: 700px;height:50px;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 200px;font-size:36px;font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center;}
button {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.display1 {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
.button1 {
    background-color: rgba(30, 31, 35);
    border: none;
    color: rgba(215, 214, 219);
    padding: 10px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="request.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="VIN" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="VIN" maxlength="100"/>
    <br>
    <div class="display1">
    <button id="submit_btn" class="button1">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>

  <br>
  <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Soap Envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
     <urn:accountInfo number="" secret="" country="US" language="en" behalfOf="?"/>
     <urn:vin>$VIN</urn:vin>
  </urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Take a look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994425/webservice-soap-request-wrong-type-of-data-sent/41101969 Maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

If your soap envelope is in a file by itself named envelope.txt, you can do this in your php page:

```
$soapenv = file_get_contents('/path/to/envelope.txt');
$prepared_envelope = str_replace("$VIN", $VIN, $soapenv);
```

This loads you envelope into a variable, then replaces the var with the value of the var.  There were a couple ways to do this, but this was easiest to explain.